# ScrollView with Accordion Lists overflowing navigator boundaries

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I need to use `ScrollView` because of the amount of data shown on the screen.
However, when it is first shown, the accordion lists are all collapsed. After any of them are expanded by a user click, the `ScrollView` (which is inside a flex layout) expands over the boundaries of the bottom navigator bar.

I wanted to limit it, say by `bottom:60`, for instance, but it is not working properly.

This is the current tag I have:

```
    <View style={{flex:10,padding:10, flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"space-around"}}>
...
        <ScrollView style={{flex:9, bottom:60}} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1, bottom:60}} >
```

I have already tried to use only the  `contentContainerStyle` property, without the `style` one, but it didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to properly setup this style?

Comment: can you share an expo snack url where i can check and revert

Comment: It looks like I partially got it. I could limit the maximum size of the ScrollView with this code:  ` <ScrollView style={{flex:7}} contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent:"flex-start", maxHeight: 300}} >`  I have the snack saved here: https://snack.expo.io/@rodhoff/bold-juice-box. However, I wanted the size of the ScrollView to be regulated according to the screensize. I have a bottom navigator of aprox 60 size (react-navigation), and I wanted for it not to hide behind it.

Comment: Almost there... I could manage to fix the dimensions with this code: `scrollDimensions = [{ 
    width:  Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width - 20),
    height: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height - 200 ) 
}];
...     let sDimensions = this.scrollDimensions;   ...          <ScrollView     

                    contentContainerStyle={[{
                        top: 100,
                        bottom: 100,
                        left: 10, 
                        right: 10, 
                        
                    }, sDimensions]} > `.  comments below ==>

Comment: Using expo, it works perfectly in the web version. However in the Android version, although the ScrollView size is perfect, it doesn't scroll properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out... hadn't noticed the `<SafeAreaView>` mentioned on the official ScrollView link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview

It works well this way:

```
scrollDimensions = [{ 
    width:  Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width - 20),
    maxHeight: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height - 200 ) 
}];

...

let sDimensions = this.scrollDimensions;

...

    <View style={{flex:20, margin:4, flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"flex-start"}}>
        <Title style={{flex:1}}>New Subject</Title>
        <SafeAreaView style={[{flex:19, }, sDimensions]}>
        <ScrollView     

                    contentContainerStyle={{}} >

...
```